# How to View the com Object Contents in SSIS

Tags: debugging, ssis, ssis-2012

I am initializing a object variable that is in the Package Scope in the script task and later that variable has to be passed to the Web Service Task.
When i View the value of the variable in the watch window after initialization in the script task, the object is initialized.
But If I see the same variable after post Execute event the value is simply displayed as System._ComObject. How to view the values are stored in the Object through Watch Window.

Comment: What does the script task do to the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to parse the object variable and output it to a flat file. This should work just fine with minor tweaks:

```
 public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    // Set up the DataAdapter to extract the data, and the DataTable object to capture those results
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Extract the data from the object variable into the table
    da.Fill(dt, Variables.LDAPResultSet);

    // Since we know the column metadata at design time, we simply need to iterate over each row in
    //  the DataTable, creating a new row in our Data Flow buffer for each
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        //'foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            {
                // Create a new, empty row in the output buffer
                LDAPOutputBuffer.AddRow();
                object[] array = dr.ItemArray;
                LDAPOutputBuffer.ADENTName = array[1].ToString();
                LDAPOutputBuffer.DisplayName = array[3].ToString();
                LDAPOutputBuffer.DNName = array[2].ToString();
                LDAPOutputBuffer.Mail = array[0].ToString();
                               }
        }
}
```

This code creates a DataTable and parses it and outputs it to a flat file destination.

Comment: But my requiremnt is to pass a object to the java web service. The value is getting filled in the script task. But while passing to web service task I am getting error. So I want to view the content of object variable on pre execute event of web service task.

Comment: Your question was to view the contents of the com object. This is one of the methods to view the variable object results. You will need to modify this code to actually fit your needs.